# How can I isolate my firewall rules in a chain such that I can reset them separately?

Tags: debian, security, iptables, firewall, iptables-redirect

I've been running some iptables rules for a while, which are (I hope) fine, no issues so far. Here's a snippet of that

```
# Block all input and forward traffic, both IPv4 and IPv6
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow traffic already established to continue
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh, dns, ldap, ftp and web services
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT

# OpenVPN tunnels
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Since I started using Docker, it's becoming extremely messy to control and reset the firewall when problems happen. If I try to reset all firewall rules, it'll mess up docker routing and nothing will work anymore.

So, it seems that the right way to solve this problem is to put all my firewall rules (the one listed above) in a separate chain. Can you please help me with that?

- How do I put all these rules in my specific chain
- How do I reset only the rules of my chain and not affect Docker rules.

### My attempt to solve the problem

If I understand correctly, I have to change the default policies to

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

to

```
iptables -A MyChain -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A MyChain -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A MyChain -P FORWARD DROP
```

and I have to add:

```
iptables -P INPUT jump MyChain
iptables -P OUTPUT jump MyChain
iptables -P FORWARD jump MyChain
```

to make the default traffic jump to my chain.

Finally, I have to add `-A MyChain` to every rules.

But some times we already have the `-A` flag. Can someone please help me understand how to edit my rules to achieve the goal of good isolation of chains?

Comment: You can create chain with `iptables -N MyChain`. In the OpenVPN tunnels part, you have two rule which doesn't do anything, you can easily detect them if you list the chain with counters (verbose).

Comment: @gabor.zed Thank you for the insight. I'm a complete ignorant in this, and quite frankly the problem with such moves is that I'm always afraid I would mess this up and make my computer vulnerable. I just had similar fiasco with postfix and spam bots have no mercy and it lead to me losing access to servers and stuff. Would you write a complete answer to my question addressing all the points?